# Question: Joining two data sets with date conditions

Tags: sql, date, join

I'm pretty new with SQL, and I'm struggling to figure out a seemingly simple task.

Here's the situation:

- I'm working with two data sets
- Data Set A, which is the most accurate but only refreshes every quarter
- Data Set B, which has all the date, including the most recent data, but is overall less accurate
- My goal is to combine both data sets where I would have Data Set A for all data up to the most recent quarter and Data Set B for anything after (i.e., all recent data not captured in Data Set A)

For example:

- Data Set A captures anything from Q1 2020 (January to March)
- Let's say we are April 15th
- Data Set B captures anything from Q1 2020 to the most current date, April 15th
- My goal is to use Data Set A for all data from January to March 2020 (Q1) and then Data Set B for all data from April 1 to 15

Any thoughts or advice on how to do this? Potentially a join function along with a date one?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/460557 and edit your question accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right.

I put in some sample data that might match your description: a date and an amount. To keep it simple, one row per any month. You can extract the quarter from a date, and keep that as an additional column, and then filter by that down the line.

```
WITH
-- some sample data: date and amount ...
indata(dt,amount) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2020-01-15', 234.45
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-02-15', 344.45
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-03-15', 345.45
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-04-15', 346.45
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-05-15', 347.45
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-06-15', 348.45
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-07-15', 349.45
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-08-15', 350.45
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-09-15', 351.45
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-10-15', 352.45
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-11-15', 353.45
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2020-12-15', 354.45
)
-- real query starts here ...
SELECT
  EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM dt) AS the_quarter
, CAST(
    TIMESTAMPADD(
      QUARTER
    , CAST(EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM dt) AS INTEGER)-1
    , TRUNC(dt,'YEAR')
    ) 
    AS DATE
  ) AS qtr_start
, *
FROM indata;
-- out  the_quarter | qtr_start  |     dt     | amount 
-- out -------------+------------+------------+--------
-- out            1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-15 | 234.45
-- out            1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-15 | 344.45
-- out            1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-03-15 | 345.45
-- out            2 | 2020-04-01 | 2020-04-15 | 346.45
-- out            2 | 2020-04-01 | 2020-05-15 | 347.45
-- out            2 | 2020-04-01 | 2020-06-15 | 348.45
-- out            3 | 2020-07-01 | 2020-07-15 | 349.45
-- out            3 | 2020-07-01 | 2020-08-15 | 350.45
-- out            3 | 2020-07-01 | 2020-09-15 | 351.45
-- out            4 | 2020-10-01 | 2020-10-15 | 352.45
-- out            4 | 2020-10-01 | 2020-11-15 | 353.45
-- out            4 | 2020-10-01 | 2020-12-15 | 354.45
```

If you filter by quarter, you can group your data by that column ...